# Constructor doesn't satisfy null safety in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Just getting started on Dart. DartPad says my code is not null-safe, but I don't see a way to initialize a "Point" without assigning a value to x and y, so it should be null-safe, shouldn't it?

```
void main(){
  Point p = new Point(1.0,2.0);
  print(p.x);
}

class Point {
  double x;
  double y;

  Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Strangely enough, it works if I use what is outlined as "syntactic sugar". But doesn't that mean that the "common way" should also work?

```
void main(){
  Point p = new Point(1.0,2.0);
  print(p.x);
}

class Point {
  double x;
  double y;

  Point(this.x, this.y) {}
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field) doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#uninitialized-variables), you should to initialize non-nullable fields **before** constructor's body.

UPD:
"Common way" in this case looks like this, using *preconstructor*:

```dart
class Point {
  double x;
  double y;

  Point(double x, double y) :
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Common way" will not work because Dart can't ensure that you will provide a non-nullable value to your variables. However, you can use the `late` keyword to tell Dart that you will.

```dart
class Point {
  late double x;
  late double y;

  Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

You can also mark `x` and `y` nullable if you don't want to use the `late` keyword:

```dart
class Point {
  double? x;
  double? y;

  Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you can avoid null safety by adding ? into variables

```
class Point {
  double? x;
  double? y;

  Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think I've already provided this solution in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849874/6618622).